How to launch Wear OS app from Phone app to start a workout even when the app is killed?
I'm developing an Android application that interacts with a Wear OS app. I want to start a workout session on the Wear OS app directly from the phone app, even if the Wear OS app is currently killed. Specifically, when a user initiates a workout on the phone, it should automatically open and start the workout on the Wear OS app.
Phone( start a workout) -> wearos app: trigger open start a workout
What I have tried so far:

Data Layer API: I've looked into the Data Layer API for communication between the phone and Wear OS, but I haven't found a way to launch the Wear OS app when it is killed.

WearableListenerService: I've implemented a WearableListenerService to receive messages on the Wear OS app, but I need guidance on how to trigger the app to open and start a workout, even if it is not running.
// Code to send a message to Wear OS app
val node = nodes[0]
val payload = "start_workout".toByteArray()
Wearable.getMessageClient(context).sendMessage(node.id, "/start_workout", payload)
        .addOnSuccessListener {
            Log.d("TAG", "Message sent successfully")
        }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.d("TAG", "Failed to send message")
        }




I'm 80% sure you can use the data layer api to launch the app even if it is killed, but anyway...
Another option is to use a remote Activity Helper to launch an intent on the watch.
private Node NODES;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    new Thread(() -> {
        Task<List<Node>> nodeListTask = Wearable.getNodeClient(getApplicationContext()).getConnectedNodes();

        try {
            NODES = Tasks.await(nodeListTask);
        } catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }).start();

    findViewById(R.id.button_id_here).setOnClickListener((l) -> {
        // the variable "i" would be the intent of you exercise app

        RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());

        for(Node n : NODES) {
    remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(i, n.getId()); 
        }
    });
}

Oh, and you will need these dependencies:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:18.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.wear:wear-remote-interactions:1.0.0


it only works when the app is in the foreground, if the app case is not open, it doesn't work for me.

You can try to start the activity as an Intent in your WearableListenerService.
class MyListenerService : WearableListenerService() {
override fun onMessageReceived(messageEvent: MessageEvent) {
    if (messageEvent.path == ACTION_PATH) {
        val startIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startIntent.addFlags(
            Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        )

        startActivity(startIntent)
    }
}


it only works when the app is in the foreground, if the app case is not open, it doesn't work for me.
